# Tailwind CSS Styles Getting Removed in Production

Tags: css, npm, tailwind-css, postcss, clean-css

My `package.json` has the following scripts:

I have the following CSS in `styles.css` (I am only using one CSS file):

```css
    .btn {
        @apply rounded py-2 px-4;
    }
    .btn.xs {
        @apply px-1;
    }
    .btn.sm {
        @apply py-1 px-2;
    }
    .btn.md {
        @apply py-2 px-4;
    }


    .btn.normal {
        border: 2px solid #A8A878;
        color: #000;
    }
    .btn.normal:hover {
        background-color: #A8A878;
        color: #FFF;
    }
    .btn.normal:focus {
        --tw-ring-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #A8A87844;
    }
```

```json
    "scripts": {
        "dev-no-watch": "postcss src/styles.css -o dist/css/styles.css",
        "dev": "postcss src/styles.css -o dist/css/styles.css --watch",
        "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production postcss src/styles.css -o dist/css/styles.css && cleancss -o dist/css/styles.css dist/css/styles.css"
    },
```

#### Running the dev script works fine, and the generated code has all of my styles.

#### Running the build script runs without errors, however, it removes **part** of my styles, which I find mind-boggling. My `.btn` styles are applied, but my `.btn.normal` styles are not.

I figured this was due to the `--tw-ring-shadow` property getting cleaned by `cleancss`, but removing the cleancss part of the build script it still has the same problem. Removing `cross-env NODE_ENV=production` solves the problem, but obviously I'd like to minify the file for production.

A friend warned that:

> If your CSS file has the Tailwind references then it'll be running purge css as part of the build process. If that's happening you can avoid that by reordering the file as explained here

And linked me here:

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/optimizing-for-production#removing-all-unused-styles

However my tailwind.config.js should be fine:

```js
module.exports = {
    purge: [
        './dist/**/*.html',
        './dist/**/*.js'
    ],
    darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
    theme: {
        extend: {},
    },
    variants: {
        extend: {},
    },
    plugins: [],
}
```

and here's my `postcss.config.js` for posterity:

```js
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        require('tailwindcss'),
        require('autoprefixer')
    ]
};
```

Some links I've looked at:

- https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/1697
- [Tailwind css purge removes all dark classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64986588/tailwind-css-purge-removes-all-dark-classes)

Answer (score 3):

My friend helped me find this one. `purgecss` removes classes it doesn't see in the html. My JS was dynamically adding buttons to the page with the classes, and purgecss didn't see them so it removed them. Adding them to an item with class hidden works

```html
<span class="hidden normal"></span>
```

Purgecss also has a whitelist option which I'll be using. Hope this answer helps anyone who is getting their custom styles removed by purge when dynamically inserting elements.

Edit: link to puprgecss safelist docs: https://purgecss.com/safelisting.html

Comment: Thank you for this. I have faced exactly the same issue and at first was not sure what is going on. After some thinking I realised that purging is not smart enough to figure out whey I construct the class names dynamically in JS. So I did the trick with the hidden div that used all those removed classes which worked. What puzzles me that not all the classes that I was dynamically adding, were removed :/

Comment: Actually, official documentation explains what is going on here: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/optimizing-for-production

Quote starts: 
"That means that it is important to avoid dynamically creating class strings in your templates with string concatenation, otherwise PurgeCSS won’t know to preserve those classes." Quote ends. 

And solution is to use "safelist" object in your `tailwind.config.js` to list all those classes that are added dynamically in a funky way (like concatenation).

Comment: As pointed by @Justin, the `safelist` key on `purgecss.config.js` would be the cleanest solution for preserving dynamically-added classes (such as those added through JS) in your production `css` file.